# optimizing ajax based search

Tags: ajax, search, grails, groovy

I am doing a ajax based search which suggests the values from the database tables as the user inputs fields in the search box. It does work but its really very slow, takes more than 10 seconds minimum for any suggestions to load. how do I optimize this to make it fast..
Like Index it/save it in cache/crawl? 
Right now autoSearch() js function is fired which retrieves data from the related table to load the suggestions. how do I make this faster?

I dont know if this will make a difference but I am using grails/groovy for application development.

Thanks
Priyank

Comment: Moving the data closer to the client will help. Whether that's moving from the database, to a cache, to the client itself. E.g. how many keys are we talking here? Is it possible to have them in memory on the server side? Is it possible to send all (or a portion) to the client up front?

Comment: Hi, I have 50,000 users, 1 million different document names, which are fields in the search..Its super sensitive data and cannot be compromised at all from security perspective, I want to make sure that nothing is disclosed to the end user at all

Comment: In your profiling, what's taking the most time? How many results do you return, and at what points in the auto-complete process?

Comment: I return results for the above specified columns -users and document names when doing user activity search so these are actually parameters for user search. The results are filtered once user types in to these search parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added an index to any searched fields (or checked in the database to make sure the examined fields are indexed)?
The Grails GORM does not automatically create indices for text fields unless you add the appropriate static mapping to your domain class.

Comment: so do I make the indexing of fields directly in database or is there a way to specify it in the domain classes?